# Value of optional type [String] not wrapped

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I'm currently a making IOS app using Stripe. When I tried to implement a Stripe card object( the image below), I got a compiler error on the line

```
var expMonth: NSNumber = Int(expArr[0])!
var expYear: NSNumber = Int(expArr[1])!
```

saying 
"Type of optional type [String] not wrapped. not unwrapped; did you mean to use ! or ??"

```
func buttonPressed(_: UIButton) {

    let creditCard = STPCardParams()
    creditCard.number = cardNumberTextField.text
    creditCard.cvc = cvvTextField.text

    if (expDateTextField.text?.isEmpty == nil){

        let expArr = expDateTextField.text?.components(separatedBy: "/")
        if (expArr?.count)! > 1 {

            var expMonth: NSNumber = Int(expArr[0])!
            var expYear: NSNumber = Int(expArr[1])!

            creditCard.expMonth = expMonth.uintValue
            creditCard.expYear = expYear.uintValue
```

How can I fix this error? Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is expArr in your code?

Comment: expArr = expiration date array. I want to let users to type the format like "MM/YYYY"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your expArr is an optional I suspect, try unwrapping it first:

```
var expMonth: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Int(expArr![0])!)
var expYear: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Int(expArr![1])!)
```

Also I'm not even sure you can directly assign an int to NSNumber as NSNumber is a pointer type but that might have changed in Swift 3.

Comment: hi Jacos. Thanks for responding! When I unwrapped like you coded, I got another error saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

Comment: Yes, as I expected you can't directly assign an int to a NSNumber, see the cast in my amended answer.

Comment: hi jacob. Thank you so much. I am applying your method now!

Comment: hi Jacob. I coded your way and the errors went away! Big thanks!

Comment: Great news! Might I ask why the other answer was accepted instead of this one?

Answer (score -1):

Converting from int to NSNumber:

```
NSNumber(value: intValue)
```

Comment: hi Bhavuk. I really appreciate your help! you were right on this.                 var expMonth: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Int(expArr![0])!)
var expYear: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Int(expArr![1])!)   the error was gone